# Help with some Graphs

Tags: plot, gnuplot, draw

I've been trying to reproduce these graphs so I can use them to a school project, but I don't know where to start. I'll be happy if someone can take his precious time and help me with some codes that I can work on on my own. It's better with such codes that I can easily modify for different tasks.

[image]

Comment: You can use [`tikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to do this. You will have to put in some work, though; this is not a do-it-for-me service. Read the documentation. It is large, but _very_ good. When you have specific question, search for it first and if you can't find an answer, ask a question with an MWE showing the problem and telling us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are standard tasks for pgfplots. Rather than reproducing these plots I just give one example. The other plots can be done similarly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,grid=major,xmin=0,xmax=9,ymin=0,ymax=90,
    xtick={1,...,8},ytick={10,20,...,80},grid style={draw=green!50!blue},
    xlabel=tid,ylabel=h\"ojd]
 \addplot[color=red!80!black,mark=*,domain=0:8,smooth,samples=9] {80-5*(x-4)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A very good answer, which gives OP what she/he is asking for: A help to start so he/she can start learning him/herself. Shame on those who voted for closing and downvoted.

Comment: I’m so grateful for your help marmot. It was a challenging thing to do for me, but you made it easier. Thank you. I'll try to read the tikz documentation so I can learn more about graphs.